# Filename passed to open system call is not null terminated

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, shellcode

I am trying to write a shellcode to create a file and write to it. File name is passed in shellcode and is not null terminated. I am getting error code -2 after open system call. 
What happens when file name passed to open system call is not null terminated?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer after some research. The file name should be null terminated. If it is not, the operating system will continue to look for a null character. Most systems have an upper limit on size of filename (including path), so if a null character is not found, then it assumes that file name exceeds the upper limit and throws an error.